# Model is null in foreach in a partial view in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

This Delete partial view is shown in a jquery dialog:

When the delete view is loaded in debug mode I see that the Model has a count of 3
but when I press the Delete button I get a NullReferenceException, that Model is Null.

How can that be?

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("Delete","Template",FormMethod.Post))
{  
    <table>
    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
            </td>  
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>      
            <td>           
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id, returnUrl = Request.Url.PathAndQuery })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
    </table>
}
```

Controller:

```
  [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Delete()
        {
            string actionName = ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
            if (Request.QueryString["content"] != null)
            {
                ViewBag.FormAction = "Json" + actionName;

                var list = new List<Template> {
                    new Template{ Id = 1, Name = "WorkbookTest"},
                    new Template{ Id = 2, Name = "ClientNavigation"},
                    new Template{ Id = 3, Name = "Abc Rolap"},
                    };

                return PartialView(list);
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.FormAction = actionName;
                return View();
            }
        }

 [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult JsonDelete(int templateId, string returnUrl)
        {
            // do I get here no !
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Json(new { success = true, redirect = returnUrl });
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed
            return Json(new { errors = GetErrorsFromModelState() });
        }
```

Update:

That code works and is supplying the correct templateId to the controller:

```
<table>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
        </td>  
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>      
        <td> 
            @using (@Html.BeginForm((string)ViewBag.FormAction, "Template"))
            {
                @Html.Hidden("returnUrl", Request.Url.PathAndQuery);
                @Html.Hidden("templateId", item.Id)               
                <input type='submit' value='Delete' />
            }
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>Judging from how your *ActionLink* is written, the *else* part of the controller is going to execute after you click delete (because *content* won't be in the query string).  That code returns View() with no model, hence the "model is null" exception.</s>

**Edit**

There are 2 problems I can see:

1. The action you're targeting is requiring a **POST**, so you need to use a form postback and not an ActionLink (which uses GET).
2. The action is expecting **templateId**, so the route attribute needs to be that.

So I'm thinking this should work:

```
@{ using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    <input type='hidden' name='templateId' value='@item.Id' />
    <input type='submit' value='Delete' />
}}
```

Comment: sorry i forgot to add the Post delete method JsonDelete which is never executed. When I click the delete link I never get into you else part you spoke of because this is the HttpGet action not post.

Comment: @Elisa, thanks, I figured something was missing but wasn't quite sure what.  Please see my updated answer.